# Changing Main Window Content from Utils Class

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

When I Try to change UI from Utils class I Get error Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in ColdStorageDesktopApp.exe

```
 class Utils
            {
                MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                private bool signedIn = false;

                public void UpdateUI()
                {
                    if (signedIn)
                    {
                        mainWindow.Sign_In_Button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        mainWindow.Sign_Out_Button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        mainWindow.Balance_Button.IsEnabled = true;
                        mainWindow.Send_Assets_Button.IsEnabled = true;
                        mainWindow.Settings_Button.IsEnabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mainWindow.Sign_In_Button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        mainWindow.Sign_Out_Button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        mainWindow.Balance_Button.IsEnabled = false;
                        mainWindow.Send_Assets_Button.IsEnabled = false;
                        mainWindow.Settings_Button.IsEnabled = false;
                    }
                }
```

and this is my MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Utils utils = new Utils();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            utils.UpdateUI();
        }
```

Comment: And what is the solution for this case?

Comment: On both sides it is needed to initialized a class in order to do something, how do you see it to break the chain?

Comment: If you're going to reference controls in the Window directly, just put the logic in to MainWindow or is that not possible? Or take out `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` in App.xaml and put the logic of window creation and setup in to App.xaml.cs

Comment: there are many pages that use this function and if so i have to write it for every class that i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StackOverflow` exception is thrown because you have an endless loop of creating object instances.

`MainWindow` creates `Utils` which creates `MainWindow` which creates `Utils` which creates `MainWindow` which creates `Utils`... etc

You shouldn't create `MainWindow` in `Utils`. There should be only one `MainWindow` instance in the app.

Instead, provide the `MainWindow` instance to the `Utils` instance as a parameter:

```
class Utils
{
    readonly MainWindow mainWindow;
    public Utils(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        this.mainWindow = mainWindow ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mainWindow));
    }
}

class MainWindow
{
    readonly Utils utils;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitilaizeComponent();
        utils = new Utils(this);
    }
}
```